# `FunctionLayer` will calculate a distance matrix

Tags: function-construction, neural-networks, configuration

I would like, that a `FunctionLayer` will calculate a distance matrix between two vectors.

I try a following approach:

````
int = NetGraph@
  FunctionLayer@Function[Block[{area1, var1, var2, d1, d2},
     
     var2 = #Priors[[2]];
     var1 = #Priors[[1]];
     
     (*area1=Map[EuclideanDistance[#,{0,1}]&,var2]]*)
     d2 = 
      Table[Map[EuclideanDistance[#, var1[[j]]] &, var1], {j, 1, 
        Length@var2}]]
    
    ]
int[<|"Priors" -> {{{55.5, 0.8}, {5.5, 0.8}}, {{22.5, 4.8}, {3.5, 
      0.8}}}|>]
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can compute the distance matrix by explicitly computing the pairwise distances.

```
dist[dim1_, dim2_] := 
 NetGraph[{"rep1" -> ReplicateLayer[dim2], "tr" -> TransposeLayer[], 
   "rep2" -> ReplicateLayer[dim1], 
   "subtract" -> ThreadingLayer[(#1 - #2)^2 &], 
   "sum" -> AggregationLayer[Total, {-1}], 
   "sqrt" -> ElementwiseLayer[Sqrt]}, {NetPort["Input1"] -> 
    "rep1" -> "subtract", 
   NetPort["Input2"] -> 
    "rep2" -> "tr" -> "subtract" -> "sum" -> "sqrt"}]
```

[image]

We can see that it produces the same results as the original function:

```
data = {{{55.5, 0.8}, {5.5, 0.8}}, {{22.5, 4.8}, {3.5, 0.8}}};
f[var1_, var2_] := 
 Table[Map[EuclideanDistance[#, var2[[j]]] &, var1], {j, 1, 
   Length@var2}]

f@data
dist[2, 2][<|"Input1" -> data[[1]], "Input2" -> data[[2]]|>]
(*{{33.2415, 17.4642}, {52., 2.}}*)
(*{{33.2415, 17.4642}, {52., 2.}}*)
```

We can also use the `FunctionLayer` like this

```
fun[dim1_, dim2_] := 
 FunctionLayer[
  Apply[Sqrt@
     AggregationLayer[
       Total, {-1}][(ReplicateLayer[{dim2}][#1] - 
         Transpose@ReplicateLayer[{dim1}][#2])^2] &]]

fun[2, 2][<|"Input1" -> data[[1]], "Input2" -> data[[2]]|>]
(*{{33.2415, 17.4642}, {52., 2.}}*)
```